# Select the records that have some value but at the same time have not other value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Before starting, thank you for your help.

My problem is: I have a table, for example, `activity_records`, that has a `date` column and a `activity_id` column.

I want to select only those dates that, for example, have the `activity_id` value of `1` but do not have the value of `2` in any of the other records having the same date.

I have tried multi-select queries and all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `not exists`:

```
select ar.*
from activity_records ar
where ar.activity_id = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from activity_records ar2
                  where r2.date = ar.date and ar2.activity_id = 2
                 );
```

Because you only want dates, an alternative is `group by`:

```
select ar.date
from activity_records ar
group by ar.date
having sum(case when ar.activity_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when ar.activity_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Or, most simply for this particular case:

```
select ar.date
from activity_records ar
where ar.activity_id in (1, 2)
group by ar.date
having max(ar.activity_id) = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks! those solutions are awesome, gonna try them all!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [date] FROM [activity_records] WHERE [activity_id] = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT [date] FROM [activity_records] WHERE [activity_id] = 2
```

See also `WHERE NOT EXISTS` and `APPLY` for more complicated scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to take only those dates with one distinct `activity_id` against it and then filtering those dates with `activity_id` = 1 by a self join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.DATE
FROM
(SELECT DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT ACTIVITY) AS COUNT_ACTIVITIES
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY DATE
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ACTIVITY) = 1) A
INNER JOIN
YOUR_TABLE B
ON A.DATE = B.DATE
AND B.ACTIVITY_ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method using not in :

select ar.* from activity_records ar where ar.activity_id = 1 and ar.date not in  (select ar2.date from activity_records ar2 where ar2.activity_id = 2 );